# Change text svg JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

How to change text assigned ID with "txtcircle" in JavaScript? My object is below:

```
<svg  width="100" height="100" id="svgcircle" > 
                <rect id="circle1" x="5" y="25" width="50" height="50" stroke="#0E0E0E" style="fill:red; stroke-width:1" />
                 <text id =txtcircle x="5" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11" fill="white" > Rect1 </text>
            </svg>
```

I also want to change text `(ID = 'Rect1')` by writing desired text with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
var elem = document.getElementById('txtcercle');
elem['innerText' in elem ? "innerText" : "textContent"] = "some value";
```